# TFS build server takes more time to build than local machine

Tags: msbuild

I'm working with an application that is constructed of several solutions.

When I build all of them on my local machine, it takes about 6 minutes.
But when building it on a TFS build server - which is a virtual machine that runs windows server 2003 R2, with TFS agent 2010, its takes up to 40 minutes.

I'm using a non-incremental build (and aware that it takes more time..), and the get-source part takes only about 2 minutes.

I can't understand why it could take such a long time compared to a local build. A solution that builds in about 1.5 minutes on my local machine takes about 9 minutes on that server.

Any ideas / tips / recommendation why this happens / how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to use a parallel build (used /m:4), but it fails, I probably have some defined wrong with the dependencies or something (I'll check that later on..).

The VM build server is a quad core, 4G RAM.

I've used MSBuild directly on that server, and a solution that takes 7.5-9.5 minutes when the agent is running a full build, took only 2.5 minutes. Is there anything the TFS build agent does that can explain this? (I REALLY can't understand this...)

Thanks ahead, young programmer.

Comment: Please elaborate on "build all of them on my local machine": Does this mean you 've used your workstation as a TFS build agent, or that you 're simply compiling the solution in VS?

Answer (score 4):

You can queue a new build, with an override on the 'Logging Verbosity' set to 'Diagnostic' (it's in the Parameters tab of Queue Build)
Once this has run, open the Build and then click on 'View Log'. In the long list that will be populated, each section will have a 'Duration' indication on the right-side.
I would study this log to find out where your delays come from.

Comment: Thanks, I've done this before and I'm going over the log. As I said in my question, I've seen that a solution that builds in 1.5 minutes on my machine, takes 9 minutes (I've seen this when Logging was set to Diagnostic)

Comment: If all your delays are of that nature it clearly seems to point to  hardware superiority of your workstation vs. your build server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to check performance summary to get why it is taking so much
   time - msbuild myproject.csproj /noconsolelogger
   /l:ConsoleLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll;performancesummary
2. Check if parallel build is enabled on the build server
3. Check your virtual machine HW is comparable to your local machine
4. Check if you have disabled antivirus to not check for viruses in the build
   directories
5. Check your performance manager why it is taking to long, what processes are running at the same time during the build process...